# Are there any good VB/C# x86 disassembler libraries?

Tags: c#, vb.net, x86, disassembly

I'm looking for a library that will disassemble x86 code into some sort of object model that I can then use to write routines that analyze the code. I'm not interested in a library that converts x86 code to text disassembly--I've found more than a few of those, but they're not that useful since I want to do some work on top of the code that I disassemble. Oh, and I'd like it to be .Net code (VB or C# preferable).

Comment: [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is your friend.

Comment: Yep! You beat me to it on that one.

Comment: So is the Reflexil plugin for Reflector for patching the assembly. ;) http://sourceforge.net/projects/reflexil/

Comment: Native x86. IL is easy... :-)

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for an x86 native code disassembler.

Comment: Reflector knows nothing about x86. This answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reflector doesn't do x86 as far as I know.

Your best bet is using the scripting or COM interface to [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/)  or [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/).

I would recommend IDA Pro if you can afford it.  IDA has a very rich API, active development and lots of documentation.  You can run it in autonomous mode, I believe using the '-AS' switch.  See http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadoc/417.htm for more info on the command line arguments.

I also ran into [libdasm](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html), but never used it, so not sure how good it is.  libdasm looks like C/C++ so it should be simple to write an API wrapper in C#.

Comment: I've used IDA Pro as a straight disassembler but I didn't think of using it because it looked like it only had internal automation. Is it possible to automate it from the outside? I guess I'm not 100% opposed to working entirely in IDA Pro, but I'd prefer to use a .Net language if I can.

Comment: Yes, you can run it in autonomous mode and specify the IDC script you'd like to run.  You can also develop using the C API and COM interfaces from the plugin API.  That's probably the best disassembly and analysis bridge you'll get.

Answer (score 4):

An old question, but if someone else comes along and you are after a 100% C# .NET implementation rather than using interop, [SharpDisasm](https://sharpdisasm.codeplex.com) provides an x86/x86-64 disassembler to both Intel and AT&T syntax. It decodes each instruction to an object that provides access to low-level information about the instruction (e.g. instruction size, operand number and types etc).

SharpDisasm is a full C# port of the [libudis86](https://github.com/vmt/udis86) C-library disassembler.

The disassembler is exposed through the `SharpDisam.Disassembler` class.

Output from the provided example console app:

```
C:\>echo a1 c9 fd ff ff a1 37 02 00 00 b8 37 02 00 00 b4 09 8a 
25 09 00 00 00 8b 04 6d 85 ff ff ff 89 45 f0| disasmcli 32

00000000 a1 c9 fd ff ff                 mov eax, [0xfffffdc9]
00000005 a1 37 02 00 00                 mov eax, [0x237]
0000000a b8 37 02 00 00                 mov eax, 0x237
0000000f b4 09                          mov ah, 0x9
00000011 8a 25 09 00 00 00              mov ah, [0x9]
00000017 8b 04 6d 85 ff ff ff           mov eax, [ebp*2-0x7b]
0000001e 89 45 f0                       mov [ebp-0x10], eax

C:\>echo 488b05f7ffffff67668b40f06766035e1048030425ffff
000067660344bef04c0384980000008048a10000000000800000 | disasmcli 64

0000000000000000 48 8b 05 f7 ff ff ff           mov rax, [rip-0x9]
0000000000000007 67 66 8b 40 f0                 mov ax, [eax-0x10]
000000000000000c 67 66 03 5e 10                 add bx, [esi+0x10]
0000000000000011 48 03 04 25 ff ff 00 00        add rax, [0xffff]
0000000000000019 67 66 03 44 be f0              add ax, [esi+edi*4-0x10]
000000000000001f 4c 03 84 98 00 00 00 80        add r8, [rax+rbx*4-0x80000000]
0000000000000027 48 a1 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00  mov rax, [0x800000000000]
```

Answer (score 4):

Necromancing, as quite some time has passed.
Yes, there are actually several.

Capstone.NET is pretty much feature-complete (libcapstone-port ARM, ARM64 (aka ARMv8/AArch64), M68K, Mips, PowerPC, Sparc, SystemZ, XCore, X86 (including X86_64). It supports most modern CPU extensions):
https://github.com/9ee1/Capstone.NET
http://www.capstone-engine.org/features.html
(MIT license)

Then, as already mentioned, there is SharpDisasm (libudis-port):
https://sharpdisasm.codeplex.com/
(Simplified BSD License (BSD))

Then there is Reko (x86-DECOMPILER) 
https://github.com/uxmal/reko
(GNU General Public License)

There is ElfSharp to read ELF files:
https://github.com/konrad-kruczynski/elfsharp
(MIT & LLVM License)

Or read the PE format like this: 
http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=572

Or using PETools:
https://github.com/jsok/PETools
(MIT License)

There's also a tool to inspect lib files:
https://github.com/BlazingHeart/SymbolExplorer

There's also an x86 assembler library:
https://code.google.com/p/managed-x86/

And the ELF hashing function 
https://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/24/calculating-elf-32-in-c-and-net

Plus there's a dedicated page at wikibooks:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers

There's also the snowman-decompiler, which uses Capstone:
https://github.com/yegord/snowman

There's also a fully managed x86 assembler:
https://github.com/meikeric/managed-x86